# Determine the last page and if max rows per page, next page

Tags: php

I got this piece of code to redirect the user to their post.

Snippet from my post script, this will get the last page:

```
// Determine on what page the post will be located
$perPage = 10;

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE topic_id = $id");
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
$page_to_redirect_to = ceil($row_count / $perPage);

// further down...

// redirect the user to their newly posted reply
header ("Location: thread.php?id=$id&page=$page_to_redirect_to#post$postid");
```

Now this works good. Until there's 10 post on the last page.

If theres, say, a topic has 75 pages and on the last page (75) it's currently 10 posts. Now if someone adds a new post I'd want them to be redirected to page 76.

How would I do that? I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following addtional statment to your code.

```
if(($row_count % $perPage)==0)
{
  $page_to_redirect_to++;
}
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, even if theres only 3 posts on the page it stills increases. I only want it to increase the page number by 1 if theres 10 posts